# What is wrong with my indoor cat palm?

Tags: houseplants, plant-care

There are black spots on my leaves, black lesions, black tips, and yellowing younger leaves. The younger leaves are most effected while the older leaves have black tips. One stem has a few black spots. What do i do?[image]